# Is there a way to stop a part of the code from working?

Tags: unity

I'm currently trying to do the death animation of my player in Unity, but since my player will be touching the ground, the death animation won't run. Is there a way to solve this?

Here is my movement code:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.position += Vector3.right * SpeedValues[(int)CurrentSpeed] * Time.deltaTime;
    
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (OnGround())
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 26.6581f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
bool OnGround()
{
    return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheckTransform.position, GroundCheckRadius, GroundMask);
}
```

Here is the death animation code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    
    Destroy(gameObject);
    LevelManager.instance.Respawn();
}
```

Comment: The `if` in your `OnCollisionEnter2D()` function only applies to `Destroy()` but looks like it was meant to apply to both `Destroy()` & the `Respawn()`. Is the conditional supposed to cover both?

Comment: Your "death animation code" does not play an animation — it just destroys the object instantly. Have you shown the right code here?

Comment: i'm sorry not animation, just the death

Comment: It's unclear to me then what you mean when you say it "won't run". Does the OnCollisionEnter function get called? Does the player object vanish and get respawned? If not, what do you observe instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is simple way to stop a part of code from working just put
`return` before the line you want to stop working.
And probably u need to change the function like this:

```
if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))   
{ 
    LevelManager.instance.Respawn();
    Destroy(gameObject); 
}
//If you need also respawn on any collision hit add this line too
LevelManager.instance.Respawn();
```